# Putting grooves into a mesh and when booleans intersect I get a weird effect

Tags: mesh

The Pictures should be the other way round but you can see that once this edge passes over the other bool edge I get this effect. What can I do to make this intersection?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, After some fiddling around I noticed that reducing the offset of my bevel helped but are there any ways around it because now I have a lot sharper edges than what I wanted

Comment: Could you upload the blender file so that we can take a closer look at what's going on?